# Draw User-Control through Graphic Object

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi

I have an event on a control that only provides a graphic object to paint to. Is it possible to load a usercontrol and have it draw to the specific graphic object?

Comment: Hm, where is the problem?  You have event (OnPaint, I suppose).  You have Graphics object.  Draw onto it, from the event.  No?

Comment: Problem is that the paint event is in another control in which I want to instantiate a user-control and have it painted to that surface?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand, but you can always pass down the Graphics object and manually call OnPaint event of any contained controls.

Comment: That's what i'm going to try next. thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Load a usercontrol" makes no meaning. If that "user-control" is another window it has to be CREATED, but this can only be done during initialization/creation of the dialog or window, not during painting.